# How to reshape this numpy array to exclude the "extra dimension"?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array `arr1` which it an output of a function. The array has an "extra" dimension caused by each element inside the numpy array being cast as a numpy array itself.

`arr1.shape` outputs `(100, 20, 1)`

If I print the array, `print(arr1[0])` outputs

```
array([[-212537.61715316],
       [   7258.38476409],
       [  37051.91250884],
       [-146278.00512207],
       [-185792.24620168],
       [-200794.59538468],
       [-195981.27879612],
       [-177912.26034464],
       [-152212.805867  ],
       [-118873.26452198],
       [ -64657.64682999],
       [ 306884.11196766],
       [-191073.9891907 ],
       [-104992.44840277],
       [ -67834.43041102],
       [ -21810.77063542],
       [  17307.24511071],
       [  55607.49775471],
       [  91259.82533592],
       [ 119207.40589797]])
```

If I reshape with `arr1.reshape((100,20))`, I get the following output for `print(arr1.reshape((100,20))[0])`:

```
array([-212537.61715316,    7258.38476409,   37051.91250884,
       -146278.00512207, -185792.24620168, -200794.59538468,
       -195981.27879612, -177912.26034464, -152212.805867  ,
       -118873.26452198,  -64657.64682999,  306884.11196766,
       -191073.9891907 , -104992.44840277,  -67834.43041102,
        -21810.77063542,   17307.24511071,   55607.49775471,
         91259.82533592,  119207.40589797])
```

My question is: how do I exclude this "extra" one, but retain the original shape of the array `arr1`?

Is the best method to use `.reshape()`? If not, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: I think you are looking for [numpy.squeeze](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html)

Comment: "how do I exclude this "extra" one, but retain the original shape of the array arr1" - you want to change the shape, but keep the original shape? You seem to be working against yourself. What *precisely* is it about the original array that you want to preserve?

Comment: @user2357112 I may be unclear. Let me edit the above. 
I am saying that my original array is an array where each float is itself an array. That's not ideal. What is the "standard Python" way to cast each element as a float?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `reshape` correctly.

```
 arr2 = arr1.reshape((100,20))
```

The shape of this will be (100,20), the same as `arr1` without the last dimension.

`arr1[0]` has shape (20,1), and thus prints as a column.

`arr2[0]` has shape (20,), and thus prints as a row(s) (count the brackets).  You might not like the display, but the shape is correct.

`squeeze` can also be used to take out the extra dimension, but the results will be same.

`print(arr2[0][:,None])` should print as a column.  It effectively adds that extra dimension back on prior to printing.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This is exactly what I was asking.

Answer (score 3):

You might be looking for `numpy.squeeze`:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html

```
a = np.arange(10*20).reshape((10, 20, 1))
print(a.shape)
# (10, 20, 1)
a = a.squeeze()
print(a.shape)
# (10, 20)
```

Note the other answer since your `reshape` should have worked you were just looking at the output incorrectly.

Comment: Perfect! I never knew this existed. Thanks!

Comment: Can you include a relevant code snippet in the body, as external links may go dead.

(Also, excellent answer, made a mental note for future use).

Comment: @ShanZhengYang Note hpaulj's answer since `reshape` should work for you too.

Comment: If one of the other dimensions just happens to have length 1, things break. I feel like `squeeze` is a dangerous convenience.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, to solve OP's original problem this just *happens* to work since there is only one dimension of size 1, but sometimes people actually want to do what `squeeze` does. So it's not dangerous, it's just useful for solving the problem that it solves.

Comment: @daveydave400 Thanks. I originally marked your answer correct, as you were there first. I *sincerely* appreciate the help!

Comment: @daveydave400 In this case, I think `squeeze` does do anything "dangerous", right?

Comment: In your specific situation `squeeze` would work, but I misread your original problem and now think `squeeze` is overkill for you. I agree that the other answer is more correct.